# Need help about jasperreport chart

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

I have a report that is I need to create a xy chart with. I have done several charts and have not come back with this error.

The report compiles fine. When I execute the chart within the application I get the following error:

Null 'orientation' argument

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots / error logs / steps to reproduce the error?

Comment: I've same problem, non of suggestions (upgrading jasperreports jar files nor manually modifying .jrxml file) could not solve my problem.
Could you find any solution for this error?!

Answer (score 1):

i was having same issue. My problem was that i had old version of jasperreport.jar on my classpath. Verify your jars

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error for a bar chart. We use ireport 4.1.2 and it has a bug: when you select 'orientation' as 'Vertical', the jrxml file is not updated with this property. So you need to switch to 'XML' view and add:
    <bar3DPlot>
    <plot orientation="Vertical" ... > 
    </bar3DPlot>